# using parent alias in sub query postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I want to use alias in sub query but seems alias is not recognized in subquery

```
SELECT M.name, (select code from menus where menus.id = M.parent_id) as parent_code
    FROM menus as M;
```

How do I achieve this?

I used to use oracle and this query works.

Comment: The syntax is correct and **will** work in Postgres. See this online example: http://rextester.com/NBZS5678 What exactly does not work for you? What is the **exact** error message you get (**[edit]** your question, do **not** post code or additional information in comments).

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT m.name
FROM menus as m
WHERE m.parent_id in (
                        select m1.parent_id 
                       from menus as m1 
                       where m.parent_id = m1.parent_id
                      );
```

Comment: That is something entirely different.